# FT232R USB UART and Android Device

Tags: android, uart

I am working on communication between an android device and the FT232R USB UART. If I insert the FT232R cable into the SAMSUNG Nexus,it works well (the test app is provided by official website: http://www.ftdichip.com/Android.htm), but when I insert it into my aigopad, the aigopad can not read any info from the FT232R, the device show that the device number is 0. So I am sure there is something wrong with my aigopad, but I do not where is the problem.

My device is aigopad M608 running android version is 4.0.4.

Looking forward to your help!

Comment: USB support within android devices is hit and miss. Each type of device will have it's own build, offten with custom configurations to enable/disable/limit features such as this. For example, the Samsung S3 has all the bells and whistles, but the Samsung Galaxy Mini has limited support for extra features.